# how to pass context correctly?

Tags: android

I get some error in the LayoutEditor.

> failed to instantiate. ... java.lang.NullPointerException

In my App I try to pass the ApplicationContext to an Class, but I get these error and i cant figure out why?
Here is the MainActivty

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static Window   window;
static Context  context;
static Consts consts;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     window = this.getWindow();
     context = this.getApplicationContext();
     consts = new Consts();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lap_timer);

}
```

And in the Consts class i try to get the context through a static Variable

```
private Context context = MainActivity.context;


public Consts() {

    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); <-- here i have the error
```

Sorry i forgot this

```
public static Consts getConsts() {
    if(_currentConsts==null)
        return new Consts();
    return _currentConsts;
}
```

this thing is very important, how to handle the constructor with this(Is in the Consts class)?

What can I do ?

Comment: Instead making context as static, pass it in constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Pass MainActivity Context to Consts Class Constructor as below.

```
consts = new Consts(MainActivity.this);
```

and assign the constructor context to a global variable context in Consts class as below.

```
Context ctx;
public Consts(Context ctx)
{
  this.ctx = ctx;
  DisplayMetrics metrics = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` you should initiate your `Consts` like:

```
Consts consts = new Consts(this);
```

and in your `Consts` class, your constructor should look like:

```
public Consts(Context context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to use static variables.

A better idea is to create a constructor in your Consts class

```
private Context context;


public Consts(Context ctx) {

    DisplayMetrics metrics = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
}
```

and then call it from your activity :

```
consts = new Consts(this);
```